# How to make virtual key presses work with video game emulators using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, input, emulation

I have tried a number of ways of making a virtual key press algorithm that works with video game emulators (specifically, VisualBoyAdvance).  All of my attempts have been unsuccessful so far, as the simulated input does not work in the emulator (though, physically pressing the keys works just fine, so it's not a mapping issue).

I have tried the simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        keybd_event(0x67, 0, 0, 0);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

and also

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

INPUT ip;

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        // Set up a generic keyboard event.
        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
        ip.ki.time = 0;
        ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

        // Press the "NUMPAD-7" key
        ip.ki.wVk = 0x67; // virtual-key code
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
        Sleep(100);

        // Release the "NUMPAD-7" key
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        Sleep(900);
    }
}
```

Both of these programs successfully type a '7' once per second into any text editor that is selected, but when I have VisualBoyAdvance selected (to which I have mapped the NUMPAD-7 key to the A button), nothing happens.  But if I then physically press NUMPAD-7, it responds to an A button press as it should.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get this code to work in a video game emulators.

Comment: I'm betting this has to do with TwitchPlaysPokemon. I think the reason it's not working is because VisualBoy uses GetAsyncKeyState rather than responding to WM_KEYDOWN/UP messages. I've not yet found a workaround myself, either.

Comment: It most certainly does.  I created the ugliest workaround for it by opening the windows virtual keyboard program, then mapping each button's x/y coordinates on my monitor (for the buttons i use as game input), then using a SetCursorPos() to move the mouse to the button and then a simulated mouse click to press the key.  It worked....if you don't want to be able to use your computer while streaming haha.

Comment: Crikey that's a hack. Perhaps you could crack open the virtual keyboard program and find what it's doing. I also stumbled across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646314(v=vs.85).aspx) but from what I can tell, I don't think it'll do the job. Good luck on your stream, I actually wrote my own implementation and urged users to use BGB (an emulator that accepts WM_KEYDOWN/UP). Maybe you could give that a go.